# Large images paint-in slowly in Chrome, progressively from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, dom-events

I'm loading some quite large images (e.g., 5000×4000, 44MB PNG) into a locally running Chrome web application, and I'm seeing the images get "painted" in slowly, from top to bottom (like an image may load slowly over a slow connection on the internet).

I'd like to wait til these images are fully rendered before fading them in. All of the typical means I have of waiting for an image to be loaded are failing me, though. My load event handlers fire, the full file size of the image is loaded, the image reports the correct height, but quite often, the image is only partially rendered and is still painting in from the top.

To make matters worse, Chrome takes an inconsistent amount of time to paint the image in. Sometimes the image is ready immediately—other times it takes almost 10 seconds. And I really can't wait an extra 10 seconds every time to make sure the image is ready to display.

Is there any event I can listen for to know when the image is fully painted in? Or is there any property I can be observing to know what amount of the image is displayed?

Comment: Have you tried [waiting for `onload` *before* inserting the image into the DOM?](https://jsfiddle.net/b4ds83n5/)

Comment: Have you thought about optimising your images? I am not surprised it takes long to paint them given the huge size, I don't think you can speed that up. Also bear in mind you are running locally, imagine how long it'll take when serving from a remote server to a user's browser

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi it's not going on the web, and it's not an option—what i've described are the parameters of the problem i'm trying to solve

Comment: @MikeC i think so, but possibly no—let me retry using something closer to what you've set up there, and i'll come back and report

Comment: @SCCOTTT ok, Mike C solution will probably work in showing the image only when fully loaded. If you'd rather not implement your own solution you could use this library https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi I think this may have done the trick! I guess I was indeed always checking the load with the image already in the DOM. Thank you! Is this worth writing up as an "Answer" that I can accept?

Comment: Got you two mixed up — @MikeC, your answer seems to work.

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi, the jQuery plugin looks to address a completely separate problem. Whether it inadvertently solves this specific issue or not, doesn't seem totally relevant unless you found the relevant piece that makes it work.

Comment: @SCCOTTT ok no problems I'll remove that, however if you look closely at the source code of that jQuery plugin it does exactly this: detect when image is in the viewport -> load the image -> only when the image is loaded make it visible.
https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/blob/master/jquery.lazyload.js#L105

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi good to know, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by @Mike C you can add the image on the DOM once it's fully loaded, [like he's done in his example.](https://jsfiddle.net/b4ds83n5/)

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://placehold.it/5000x5000';
img.onload = function() {
    var loadingEl = document.querySelector('p');
  loadingEl.parentNode.removeChild(loadingEl);
  document.body.appendChild(img);
};
```